# My JavaScript mp3 player isn't playing the next song, when the current song is manually selected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a JavaScript MP3 player and followed an online tutorial. I've added some things myself, like a list of MP3-files that can be clicked to play them. The whole thing works fine, until I manually select an MP3 file and the song ends or I click next (or prev), because it won't load the next song (this does work, if you don't manually click on a song.)

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at loadSong (player.js:20)
    at next (player.js:76)
    at HTMLElement.onclick (VM4443 :88)
```

I think it has something to do with the parameter given in loadSong(id). The code is below (unnecessary code has been left out), thanks in advance for the help!

```
var songs = ["Bloed Voor De Kunst.mp3",
            "Iemand Moet Het Doen.mp3"];

var songTitle = document.getElementById('songTitle');
var songList = document.getElementById('songList');
var arrayLength = songs.length-1;

var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;

function loadSong(id) {
    currentSong = id;
    song.src = "mp3/" + songs[currentSong]; 
    var title = songs[currentSong];
    var trim = title.substr(0, title.length-4);
    songTitle.textContent = trim;
    song.volume = volumeSlider.value;
    song.play();
    setTimeout(showDuration, 1000);
    document.getElementById('playpause').setAttribute('onclick','songPlayPause()');
    document.getElementById('playpause').setAttribute('class','far fa-pause-circle');
    console.log(currentSong);
    console.log(arrayLength);
}

function updateSongSlider() {
    var c = Math.round(song.currentTime);
    songSlider.value = c;
    currentTime.textContent = convertTime(c);
    if(song.ended) {
        next();
    }
}

function next() {
    var current = currentSong;
    if(current !== arrayLength) {
        currentSong = currentSong + 1;      
    }
    else {
        currentSong = 0;
    }
    loadSong(currentSong);

}

function getSongList() {
    for(var i=0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        var title = songs[i];
        var trim = title.substr(0, title.length-4);
        var playbutton = "<i class='far fa-play-circle' onClick=loadSong('" + i + "')></i>";
        document.getElementById('songList').innerHTML += "<li>" + playbutton + "<p>" + trim + "</p></li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your array `songs` doesn't contain a song related to the key `id` at this moment. So the `id` isn't a good value.

In your condition `current !== arrayLength`, `current` as its maximum is probably here a string `"1"` which isn't exactly equal to the number `1`, so it enters in the condition and makes the addition which results to a wrong value.

Change :

```
function next() {
    var current = currentSong;
    if(current !== arrayLength) {
        currentSong = currentSong + 1;      
    }
    else {
        currentSong = 0;
    }
    loadSong(currentSong);

}
```

To :

```
function next() {
        var current = parseInt(currentSong);
        if(current < arrayLength) {
            currentSong = currentSong + 1;      
        }
        else {
            currentSong = 0;
        }
        loadSong(currentSong);
    }
```

Comment: Tried it and this works, but inconsistently. You get an error now and then if you press next multiple times but if works like 60% of the time. What do you think i should do with the ID?

Comment: `if else` is not neccessary, uses like `loadSong(currentSong++%songs.length)`

Comment: I edited my answer to make sure you are getting a number here : `var current = parseInt(currentSong);`